# the is stopped when clicking listView item

Tags: android

The app start with no problem and it stops when I click on any item on the listView. The message says "Unfortunately, AppName has stopped". Any help? 
Here is my main activity class:

```
products.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {//THE ERROOR SHOULD BE HERE          


public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> info, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListItemActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
}           
});
```

Here are the error messages in the log:

```
03-17 00:05:56.497: D/AndroidRuntime(14617): Shutting down VM
03-17 00:05:56.497: W/dalvikvm(14617): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x417f5898)
03-17 00:05:56.497: E/AndroidRuntime(14617): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-17 00:05:56.497: E/AndroidRuntime(14617): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.a2_alwehaibia1_grocery/com.example.a2_alwehaibia1_grocery.ListItemActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
03-17 00:05:56.497: E/AndroidRuntime(14617):    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1645)
03-17 00:05:56.497: E/AndroidRuntime(14617):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1441)
03-17 00:05:56.497: E/AndroidRuntime(14617):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3464)
03-17 00:05:56.497: E/AndroidRuntime(14617):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3425)
03-17 00:05:56.497: E/AndroidRuntime(14617):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3661)
03-17 00:05:56.497: E/AndroidRuntime(14617):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3629)
03-17 00:05:56.497: E/AndroidRuntime(14617):    at com.example.a2_alwehaibia1_grocery.MainActivity$1.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:63)
03-17 00:05:56.497: E/AndroidRuntime(14617):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:301)
03-17 00:05:56.497: E/AndroidRuntime(14617):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1510)
03-17 00:05:56.497: E/AndroidRuntime(14617):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3339)
03-17 00:05:56.497: E/AndroidRuntime(14617):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
03-17 00:05:56.497: E/AndroidRuntime(14617):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-17 00:05:56.497: E/AndroidRuntime(14617):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-17 00:05:56.497: E/AndroidRuntime(14617):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
03-17 00:05:56.497: E/AndroidRuntime(14617):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-17 00:05:56.497: E/AndroidRuntime(14617):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-17 00:05:56.497: E/AndroidRuntime(14617):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
03-17 00:05:56.497: E/AndroidRuntime(14617):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
03-17 00:05:56.497: E/AndroidRuntime(14617):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Logcat clearly saying `ListItemActivity have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to declare the activity in manifest file

```
 <activity
        android:name="com.example.a2_alwehaibia1_grocery.ListItemActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
 </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly declare each and every activity that you use in your application within the android manifest file. For example, you need to do:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.a2_alwehaibia1_grocery.ListItemActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
</activity>
```